# How can I use a mask modifier with a musgrave texture?

Tags: materials, node-editor, masking

I'm trying to make a simple version of the masking technique used here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFYFh8w4758
in (0:00 --> 0:06)

is there a way to achieve this effect using a mask modifier or anything else?
Thanks!

Comment: is it supposed to be animated?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: sort of
[image]

This setup will make the parts of your mesh transparent where the musgrave texture is black. If you want to see the backside, or other objects through it, replace the holdout by transparent. 
However the edges of the mask won't look 3D, the ones in the clip seem to have some depth, this method won't allow that, but maybe it's enough to get started. With animation nodes you can assemble your own meshes, it won't be easy, but in my opinion that would be the proper way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by mixing your material with a `Transparent BSDF` where the `Musgrave Texture` (or any other texture) is used as the mixfactor.

The `Musgrave Texture` on its own will produce a soft fade in transparency.
To get the hard contours we see in the video a `Math Node` set to `Greater Than` or a `ColorRamp` between the texture and the `Mix Shader` can be used.

[image: Blender Musgrave Transparent Mask]

If you are using EEVEE the `Properties Window > Material > Settings > Blend Mode` has to be set to something other than `Opaque` to enable transparency.